# Couldn't activate the CDP compatibility in the HP V1910 web interface

Tags: switch, hp, lldp, cdp

I tried to enable both LLDP and CDP from the web interface of my V1910 switch, but every time I select enable the session logs out. I found a command to enable the LLDP from the the switch's terminal. But I couldn't find the equivalent to enable the CDP compatibility. Any ideas to why I can't enable these two protocols from the web interface or how I can enable CDP from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to activate the CDP compatibility on a HP V1910-24G Switch:

```
> [MySwitch] lldp compliance cdp
```

And then I activate the cdp in the proper interfaces

```
> [interface 1] lldp compliance admin-status cdp txrx
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can glean from the user manual, HP considers CDP a mode of LLDP. The manual calls it "the CDP compatibility of LLDP." You need to enable LLDP and CDP both globally and on the port.

> LLDP-CDP PDUs use only SNAP encapsulation.

[Here is the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/633028/Hp-V1910.html?term=cdp&selected=1&page=239#manual), and the bottom of page 239 and page 240 have the instructions.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do; every time I try to enable The CDP Compatiblity of LLDP as described in the manual, the page logs out without enabling the protocols. I did the lldp from terminal but can't find the command that will enable the cdp compatibility.

Comment: You set the ports then set the global? Did you change the encapsulation to SNAP?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't register my choice of SNAP, it always comes back as ETHII.

Comment: You may need to upgrade or downgrade the software. You may have a version with a bug. The manual is pretty clear, and if it doesn't work the way the manual says, you probably have a software problem.

Comment: I just did the upgrade but the same thing keeps happening.